# Название профессии "золотарь"

Tags: этимология

Почему ассенизаторов раньше называли "золотарями"? Причём тут золото?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос. Асс**е**низаторы только. 
"Золотарь" имело два значения: тот, кто работает с золотом и тот, о ком вы спрашиваете. 
Последнее значение вторично и представляет собой типичный пример народного сарказма.
Название от противного, так сказать. 
Дополнительным фактором для закрепления значения, возможно, стали эвфемистические мотивы. Основное название "этого" старались особо не употреблять.

Answer (score 2):

Основное значение слова "золотарь" - золотых дел мастер. А в значении "ассенизатор" использовался как эвфемизм (замена неблагозвучного, неприличного, неуместного слова), обычно такое использование слова "золотарь" носило шутливый характер.